# How to pass Json parameters to powershell script

Tags: json, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I would like to pass Json data to Powershell script.

**PowerShell script:**

Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Out-File "file.json"

New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name “” -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-core" -EndIPAddress "" -StartIPAddress ""

In the above powershell script I need to get values to "" from Json file mentioned below.So how to get Json parameter values during run time and all 3 parameters should be passed to the above command and so that it will create new firewall rule to new DB server.

Also, when I run the powershell command (**Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Out-File "file.json"**) I am getting my Json file data in the below format.Not sure whether this format looks good but I need the below values start from pdbr_home,1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 and similarly another 2 rows of data should be passed to my powershell command here **New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name “” -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-core" -EndIPAddress "" -StartIPAddress "".** via for loop.

**file.Json:**

```
      [
        {
        "EndIPAddress": "1.3.2.2",
        "Id": "/subscriptions/abcdefg/resourceGroups/dev/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/db-dev-  vm/firewallRules/praveen_Home",
        "Name": "praveen_Home",
        "StartIPAddress": "4.3.1.2",
        "Type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules"
      },
      {
        "EndIPAddress": "2.4.5.6",
        "Id": "/subscriptions/abcdefg/resourceGroups/dev/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/db-dev-  vm/firewallRules/pdbr_Home",
        "Name": "pdbr_Home",
        "StartIPAddress": "3.2.1.2",
        "Type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules"
      }
    ]
```

The below command output as follows.

PS /home/praveen> Get-Command *json*

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-Json                                   7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Json                                     7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          Test-Json                                          7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Application     json_pp                                            0.0.0.0    /usr/bin/json_pp
Application     json_pp                                            0.0.0.0    /bin/json_pp
```

**Error:**

Error:

```
New-AzMySqlFirewallRule: /home/praveen/dbtest.ps1:21
Line |
  21 |  …  -ServerName "praveen-dev" -EndIPAddress $entry.EndIPAddress -StartI …
     |                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'EndIPAddress' because it is an empty string.
```

Final solution worked for me now:

##################### Updating Firewall rules from Soiurce DB server to Target DB server ##################

```
Write-Host -NoNewline "Updating Firewall rules from Soiurce DB server to Target DB server"
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SourceDBServerName | Select-Object Name, StartIPaddress, EndIPaddress | Convertto-Json | Out-File "firewallrule.json"
foreach ($frule in (Get-Content firewallrule.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)) {
  New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name $frule.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetDBServerName -EndIPAddress $frule.EndIPAddress -StartIPAddress $frule.StartIPAddress
}
```

Comment: [1] PLEASE wrap your code in formatting markers. ///// the sample JSON you posted does not look like proper JSON. have you looked at the result of `Get-Command *json*` yet? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  Yes, it was not formatted as I did wanted to show that to you why it was generated improperly and the above json code format has been generated when I run the following command: Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Out-File "file.json"

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Now after sharing the command below by An-dir I have run the command and updated Json data above. Now can you please help me to iterate Json data through for loop using powershell script.

Now, I want to pass Name,StartIP address, EndIP address of Json data to the below command while creating new firewallrule for another DB.

New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name “” -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-core" -EndIPAddress "" -StartIPAddress "". via for loop.

Please share the for loop how to iterate the above Json parameters to the powershell command.

Comment: you convert data to JSON format _and back again_ using the JSON cmdlets. **_again, take a look at `Get-Command *json*` for the how-to._** [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have ran the command Get-Command *json* and the result is as updated above.Now can you please let me know how to pass parameters from Json to powershell script.

Comment: you seem to have a different focus now ... that means you should ask a new Question instead of adding to the current one.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey No, my original question is How to pass Json parameters to powershell script ? Conversation has started from that point and I still require solution that how to pass Json parameters to powershell script via for loop. Please help me.

Comment: the JSON you posted is not valid. please fix that ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have fixed my Json and updated above. Could you please help me now?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Any update you can provide here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this solution with help of all the above inputs few days ago. Thanks to all.Really appreciated your help.

##### Updating Firewall rules from Source DB server to Target DB server

```
Write-Host -NoNewline "Updating Firewall rules from Soiurce DB server to Target DB server"
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SourceDBServerName | Select-Object Name, StartIPaddress, EndIPaddress | Convertto-Json | Out-File "firewallrule.json"
foreach ($frule in (Get-Content firewallrule.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)) {
  New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name $frule.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetDBServerName -EndIPAddress $frule.EndIPAddress -StartIPAddress $frule.StartIPAddress
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Convertto-Json before writing file.
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2

```
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Convertto-Json | Out-File "file.json"
```

EDIT as requested:

```
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Select-Object Name,"StartIP address", "EndIP address"| Convertto-Json | Out-File "file.json"
```

Another EDIT as requested (fixed my mistake - thank you @sage pourpre):

```
foreach ($entry in (Get-Content file.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json) {
    New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -name $entry.Name `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev" `
    -ServerName "dev-core" `
    -StartIPAddress $entry.StartIPAddress `
    -EndIPAddress $entry.EndIPAddress
}
```

Comment: Now the format is working fine after I run the command below.
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Convertto-Json | Out-File "file.json"

Now, I want to pass Name,StartIP address, EndIP address to the below command while creating new firewallrule for another DB.

Comment: Any update from your end please?

Comment: Just edited my code. Check If that is what you need

Comment: Now,I need to pass those parameters from JSON to powershell script one by one using for loop in powershell. Here in JSON script will have multiple values for the 3 parameters and those I need to pass 3 Params at a time and again 3 params at time to the below powershell command.  There I got stuck actually. Can you please help there? Here the below command needs to pick the 3 parameter values from json and should execute the below command:                                New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name “” -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-core" -EndIPAddress "" -StartIPAddress "".

Comment: Made one more edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have run the command provided by you below.I am getting the error while executing it and error is updated above. Please help me out where is the issue. When I open file.Json I can see everything proper and clear.

foreach ($entry in (Get-Content file.json -raw | ConvertTo-Json)) {
    New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -Name $entry.Name -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "praveen-dev" -EndIPAddress $entry.EndIPAddress -StartIPAddress $entry.StartIPAddress
}

Comment: I am eagerly looking for your update @An-dir . Please provide your update so that it will be more helpful.

Comment: In your last example, you used `ConvertTo-Json`. I believe you intended `ConvertFrom-Json` there :) (eg: `(Get-Content file.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)`

Comment: @SagePourpre Yes you are absolutely correct. I made that change when I realised and it worked if I use ConvertFrom-Json instead of ConvertTo-Json. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server" | Convertto-Json | Out-File "file.json"

$data = Get-Content "C:\Users\me\file.json" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json #replace path to where you have exported the json file


foreach ($line in $data) {
    New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -name $line.Name `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev" `
    -ServerName "dev-core" `
    -StartIPAddress $line.StartIPAddress `
    -EndIPAddress $line.EndIPAddress
}
```

A different method, although the question is for JSON, would be to just store the rules in a variable.

```
        $rules = Get-AzMySqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "dev" -ServerName "dev-DB-Server"
    
    foreach ($rule in $rules){
        New-AzMySqlFirewallRule -name $rule.Name `
            -ResourceGroupName "dev" `
            -ServerName "dev-core" `
            -StartIPAddress $rule.StartIPAddress `
            -EndIPAddress $rule.EndIPAddress
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late, I was able to fix this and solution is updated above.

Answer (score 0):

//role-definition.json

```
{
    "RoleName": "MyReadWriteRole",
    "Type": "CustomRole",
    "AssignableScopes": ["/"],
    "Permissions": [{
        "DataActions": [
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/*",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Coverting it into json object as i need to pass it as an argument in a powershell parameter.
So i did below -

1. Created a powershell parameter

   $roleDef= @"
   {
   "RoleName": "MyReadWriteRole",
   "Type": "CustomRole",
   "AssignableScopes": ["/"],
   "Permissions": [{
   "DataActions": [
   "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata",
   "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/*",
   "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/*"
   ]
   }]
   }
   "@
2. $jsonObject = $roleDef | ConvertFrom-Json
3. az cosmosdb sql role definition create --account-name cosmosdbaccname --resource-group 'my-rg' --body $jsonObject

but I get below error -
Failed to parse string as JSON:
@{RoleName=MyReadWriteRole; Type=CustomRole; AssignableScopes=System.Object[]; Permissions=System.Object[]}
Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @EZRyan - Any help on above?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33312340)